# AngularJS is not found in Hybrid app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack-2

I'm building a POC of Angular 1+2 Hybrid application. I have managed to run it and now I'm trying to introduce Webpack.

I get a `Error: AngularJS v1.x is not loaded!` error when bootstrapping the module. I've checked - the angular is loaded when initializing the module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Entry file:

```js
import { downgradeInjectable, downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HelloAngular2} from './components/hello-angular2';
import {TimeZonesService} from './services/timezones';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import * as angular from 'angular';

angular.module('scotchTodo', [/*'todoController', 'todoService'*/]);
angular.module('scotchTodo').directive('helloAngular2', downgradeComponent({ component: HelloAngular2}));
angular.module('scotchTodo').factory('timeZones', downgradeInjectable(TimeZonesService));   

@NgModule({
 declarations: [HelloAngular2],
 entryComponents: [HelloAngular2],
 imports: [BrowserModule, UpgradeModule],
 providers: [TimeZonesService]
})
class MyNg2Module {
    ngDoBootstrap() {};
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyNg2Module).then(platformRef => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['scotchTodo']);
});
```

Webpack config:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
  entry: {
    app: __dirname + '/public/js/boot.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'app-loader.js'
  },
  resolve:{
      extensions: ['.js'],
      alias: {
          'controllers/main.js': 'controllers/main.js',
          'services/todos.js':'services/todos.js'
      }
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public/jslibs",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Bootstrap generated part that has angular defined:

```js
angular.module('scotchTodo', []);
angular.module('scotchTodo').directive('helloAngular2', static_1.downgradeComponent({ component: hello_angular2_1.HelloAngular2 }));
angular.module('scotchTodo').factory('timeZones', static_1.downgradeInjectable(timezones_1.TimeZonesService));
var MyNg2Module = (function () {
    function MyNg2Module() {
    }
    MyNg2Module.prototype.ngDoBootstrap = function () { };
    ;
    return MyNg2Module;
}());
MyNg2Module = __decorate([
    core_1.NgModule({
        declarations: [hello_angular2_1.HelloAngular2],
        entryComponents: [hello_angular2_1.HelloAngular2],
        imports: [platform_browser_1.BrowserModule, static_2.UpgradeModule],
        providers: [timezones_1.TimeZonesService]
    })
], MyNg2Module);
platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyNg2Module).then(function (platformRef) {
    var upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(static_2.UpgradeModule);
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['scotchTodo']);
});
```

--UPDATE--

After adding ProvidePlugin with this config:

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'angular': 'angular'
})

the `Error: AngularJS v1.x is not loaded!` error which I presume came from Upgrade module has disappeared.
Now the angular is undefined in `angular.module` because angular is imported by `__webpack_require__`

--UPDATE 2--

It seems like the problem is that AngularJS doesn't support CommonJS style module.exports. I'm trying to use `exports-loader` but it doesn't work now. The config is:

```
loaders: [
      { test: /[\/]angular\.js$/, loader: "exports-loader?angular" }
    ]
```

--UPDATE 3--

After adding `module.exports = windows.angular;` to the bootstrap generated file there is no error. But application still doesn't work because there is no `resumeBootstrap` function for angular available.

--UPDATE 4--

Here is the main page HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">

    <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>I'm a Todo-aholic <span class="label label-info">{{ todos.length }}</span></h1>
    </div>

    <!-- TODO LIST -->
    <div id="todo-list" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">



            <!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"> {{ todo.text }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <p class="text-center" ng-show="loading">
                <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></span>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- FORM TO CREATE TODOS -->
    <div id="todo-form" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <!-- BIND THIS VALUE TO formData.text IN ANGULAR -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="I want to buy a puppy that will love me forever" ng-model="formData.text">
                </div>

                <!-- createToDo() WILL CREATE NEW TODOS -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center text-muted">
        <p>A demo by <a href="http://scotch.io">Scotch</a>.</p>
        <p>Read the <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular">tutorial</a>.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

--UPDATE--

setting the `window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";` helps Angular to init `resumeBootstrap` function but the application still doesn't work

Comment: Any resolution?  I am currently running into the same issue and it appears the code is very similar to mine :-)

Comment: can try and import with side effects for webpack in a sample import only entry point and then include that in your index.html

Comment: @harishr I didn't get what you mean, what is side effects import?

Comment: I've added `ProvidePlugin` to a webpack config and configured in for angular. Now it can resolve angular inside a webpack module builder it is still unavailable in main code - it looks like it importing the wrong module.

Comment: you are going to mess yourself for sure. Angular2 encapsulates angular1 then why you are looking to combine both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you have issues mixing Angular 1 & 2. You might have missed few things during set-up.

I stumbled upon this blog post which was helpful:

https://medium.com/@SevenLee/configuration-tips-to-build-hybrid-angular-1-and-angular-2-project-in-real-world-230b715629dc#.r57e4561a

Also, how does your html look like?

**UPDATE**

Angular 1 => Webpack

Angular 2 => Webpack 2

Regarding [Webpack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) the git repository advises you to use a different kit made for Angular 1, which means you cant use Angular 1 with that Webpack.

They advise you tu use [NG6](https://github.com/angularclass/NG6-starter) instead:

*"If you're looking for Angular 1.x please use [NG6-starter](https://github.com/angularclass/NG6-starter) If you're looking to learn about Webpack and ES6 Build Tools check out ES6-build-tools If you're looking to learn TypeScript see TypeStrong/learn-typescript If you're looking for something easier to get started with then see the angular2-seed that I also maintain angular/angular2-seed"*

Cheers

Comment: thank you! but his post describes just how to run them both using systemJS runtime module resolution and I want to use the webpack to make a package

Comment: Alright I understand. It is because Angular 1 and Webpack for Angular2 are not compatible. For that you will need to use a different library. It is mentioned in the [webpack's github](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).
Then try using [NG6](https://github.com/angularclass/NG6-starter), I dont think it has the exact same features but it should do the job.